# Displaying Text Label from a combined Array (using APIs)

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, restkit

**I have a combined array, that is combining the news headline results of API1 and API2.  How do I get the "headline text" from each object in the new combined array?**

Right now I have the app working fine when I'm only using one of the API's at a time.  But now that I'm putting the objects in a combined array, I can't figure out how to display the `cell.headline.text` since the sources I'm pulling from aren't from the same exact JSON anymore (i.e. could be pulling from API1 or could be pulling from API2).

*I'm using RestKit.*

**WebListViewController.m (Only using API1)**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WebListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WebListCell"];

    F *fLocal = [hArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *headlineText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fLocal.headline];
    cell.headlineLabel.text = headlineText;
}
```

**WebListViewController.m (Only using API2)**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WebListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WebListCell"];

    D *dLocal = [iArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *otherHeadlineText = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dLocal.head.headline];
    cell.headlineLabel.text = otherHeadlineText;
}
```

**WebListViewController.m (Trying to Combine API1 + API2)**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// This is where I need help.  Don't know if this line below even makes sense?
    WebListViewController *combinedArray = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say anything about your RestKit usage, and using core data would probably be a great idea for you. You should also think about mapping all of the objects into the same destination object / entity.

Anyway, you can merge your arrays to get a list of just the headline texts with:

```
combinedArray = [hArray valueForKey:@"headline"];
combinedArray = [combinedArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[iArray valueForKey:@"head.headline"]];
```

*(can't test right now, second line may require `valueForKeyPath:`)*

Comment: What info would you like me to expound on regarding my RestKit usage?

Comment: First off, can you use Core Data? Second, can you use a single entity for both 'type's of headline? Need to decide the appropriate approach to solving the problem first...

Comment: I'd prefer not to use Core Data since I'm unfamiliar, unless it's the only solution. What information would you need to know if a single entity was possible? Thanks!

Comment: You to tell me ;-) What are your classes, how are they different. Did my answer work to get you an array of strings? What different do you need?

Comment: I guess the problem is that if I get just an array of headlines, in the cell that hold the headline there will also be the image and date etc associated w the headline. Will your suggestion disassociate the headline from the date/image/etc? What do you think the best solution is?

Comment: Basically I'm pulling in news stories from CNN and MSN, combining into a tableview sorted by date. I'm just not fully able to wrap my head around how that happens.

Comment: Yes, it will, you didn't ask about that... I think the best solution it to ask a question about your data source and model, and how to get one into the other in a way that enables the UI you want. At the moment you should use Core Data and a single `NewsItem` entity...

Comment: Got it so just ask a new question then. I mean I know this has to be something that isn't too difficult, because there are so many apps that do this sort of thing, I guess I just don't know how to get the perfect words to answer the question

Comment: What your suggesting though your saying will work just fine for me though?

Comment: The general idea is that you can use RestKit to map arbitrary source data into your data model objects. That isn't 100%, if the source data is messy / significantly different then there are issues. But the point is that the app has 1 common data model, and you take the data from the outside world, wash off all the dirty bits and store it in the best way for your usage.

Comment: That is a beautiful way of stating it, and conceptually makes a lot of sense. I just haven't got the full idea of how to technically implement it. But I'll keep working on it. Thanks

Comment: Start by creating a data model that contains what you want in a good way for your usage. Then worry about how to import data into that model. Get the app structure correct first. I really recommend Core Data for you, and `NSFetchedResultsController` to display your contents on table views.

Answer (score 0):

Why combine the arrays?

```
F *fLocal = [hArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
D *dLocal = [iArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString * combinedHeadlineText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fLocal.headline, dLocal.head.headline];

cell.headlineLabel.text = combinedHeadlineText;
```

Comment: Because I don't want the Api1 headline and Api2 headline to be combined. What I'm trying to do is essentially get cnn headlines and msn headlines, and then put them in a table view together. So I wouldn't want the ccn headline and msn headlines appended to each other. Make sense? Thanks!